# ReactiveCocoa 4 MVVM best practice with HTTP requests

Tags: swift, mvvm, swift2, ios9, reactive-cocoa

I'm working on the login part of my app and I thought of using ReactiveCocoa 4. :)

This is in my view's init:

```
self.viewModel.loginSignal = self.LoginButton.rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)!

self.viewModel.loginStatus.producer.startWithNext({ status in
  self.setLoginButtonStatus(status)
})

self.viewModel.initSignals()
```

Where `setLoginButtonStatus` will just disable/enable the button, etc. and `status` is just an enum.

And this is in my view model's `initSignals()`

```
self.loginSignal!.toSignalProducer().start({ sender in
  self.validateLoginInput()
})
```

Where `loginSignal` is declared as `var loginSignal: RACSignal?`.

This is in my `validateLoginInput`

```
self.loginStatus.value = MyStatus.Login.IN_PROGRESS // So button would be disabled

session.rac_dataWithRequest(request).map({ data, response in
  return MyResponse(data, response)
}).startWithNext({ response
  // Say MyResponse class would check the reponse if login is successful
  if response.isSuccessful() {
    self.loginStatus.value = MyStatus.Login.SUCCESS
  } else {
    self.loginStatus.value = MyStatus.Login.FAIL
  }
})
```

The view should disable the button at first, then re-enable it when the session finishes and when `response.isSuccessful()` is true.

Well, it works for now, but I am wondering if **I am using MVVM with ReactCocoa 4 appropriately.**

Also, I've been getting a "warning" that bothers me a bit. This appears like a second after the HTTP request gets is response.

```
2015-12-02 12:15:32.566 MyProject[460:48610] This application is
modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can
lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an
exception in a future release.
```

**Is it because I'm using `v4.0.0-alpha.4` on `Swift 2.1`?** This actually *delays the re-enabling of my button*.

I'm getting confused with the examples in the web as most of them are in Objective-C and I think some function names changed, etc...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Others can speak about the *MVVM* approach you're taking, but regarding the warning you're seeing: that's because you're using *UIKit* from a background thread. I imagine this comes from the `self.setLoginButtonStatus` call. Depending on what signals your binding to that property it's possible (and it's happening in this case) that the values emitted by its producer **are not emitted on the main thread**.

To fix that, you can use `observeOn`, to forward values to the main thread:

```
self.viewModel.loginStatus
    .producer
    .observeOn(UIScheduler())
    .startWithNext { status in
          self.setLoginButtonStatus(status)
    )
```